# PPPOE internet not working in ubuntu,but it works on Windows

Tags: windows, internet, connection, pppoe

I have a PC that connects to the internet with a cable. I have no router or anything like that. Just plug the cable, enter the username and passwords and it's done.

On my laptop, I have both Windows and Ubuntu. When I plug the cable into my laptop it doesn't connect. I changed the MAC address on my Laptop (in Windows) and made it the same address that my PC has. Since I did that it worked, but only under Windows. In Ubuntu it seems I have some problem (I'm new).

I tried changing the MAC address under Ubuntu too, but I didn't receive connection. (I typed `sudo pppoeconf` in the terminal and made the network, but I have no internet access).

And I seem to notice that I don't have eth0. Instead I have enp2s0 and lo.

PS. Wi-fi works, but not PPPoE. 
Also, when I create "Wired connection" It doesn't show in the tab "Ethernet Network". Instead it is "device not managed".

Comment: Don't put "Solved" in the title. Instead, mark your answer as "Solved" by clicking the check mark next to it. (Note it may be unavailable for up to 48 hours.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it. Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` as root, and delete every line except these:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Then

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Then created (not `pppoeconf`) DSL connection where I entered my username and password, and the cloned MAC address of my PC.